# Set default value inside ngSelect

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a a ngSelect with some options in it.

```
<select data-ng-model="type" data-ng-change="option(type)">
   <option data-ng-repeat="type in languages" value="{{type.i18n}}">
        {{type.language}}
    </option>
</select>
```

And a Controller

```
angular.module('navigation', [])
.controller('NavCtrl',['$scope','$translate', function($scope,$translate){

    $scope.option = function(type){
        console.log(type) //this display the i18n value of languages
        $translate.use(type);
    }

    $scope.languages = [
        { language: "English", i18n: "en_EN"},
        { language: "Swedish", i18n : "se_SE" }
    ];
}])
```

I want the ngSelect to have a default option, in my case: "English". I've tried to set it to:

```
$scope.type = $scope.languages[0].language; // English
$scope.type = $scope.languages[0]; //The whole darn json object.
```

Help please?

Comment: change $scope.type to $scope.tVal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this way

```
<select  ng-model="selectedlanguage" ng-change="option(this.selectedlanguage)"  ng-options="i.language for i in languages">
            </select>
```

//Js code

```
angular.module('navigation', [])
.controller('NavCtrl',['$scope','$translate', function($scope,$translate){

    $scope.option = function(type){
        console.log(type) //this display the i18n value of languages
        $translate.use(type);
    }

    $scope.languages = [
        { language: "English", i18n: "en_EN"},
        { language: "Swedish", i18n : "se_SE" }
    ];

    **$scope.selectedlanguage = $scope.languages[0];**
}])
```

Comment: I've tried this way:

<select data-ng-change="option()" data-ng-model="type" data-ng-options="value.i18n as value.language for value in languages" >
          <option ng-selected="value[0].language">
          </option>
       </select>

Gave exactly the same output. Still no default value. Your option value comes out undefined.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm, the <option> tag is hence unnecessary?

Comment: You don't want option tag, see my answer totally . Happy coding dude :)

Answer (score 4):

how about using `ngSelected`? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

```
<option ng-selected="$index==0"></option>
```

or

```
<option ng-selected="type.language=='English'"></option>
```

Comment: Ah, tried it again and works. But looks like Ramesh answer is more correct, since you don't have to use <option> at all.

Answer (score 3):

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/yv8gew3IDGxjH666UmlC?p=preview

```
<select data-ng-model="selectedType">
  <option data-ng-repeat="lang in languages" value="{{lang.i18n}}">
    {{lang.language}}
  </option>
</select>
```

**JS**:

```
.controller('NavCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.$watch('selectedType', function(type){
        if (!type) return;
        console.log(type) //this display the i18n value of languages
        // $translate.use(type);
    });

    $scope.languages = [
        { language: "English", i18n: "en_EN"},
        { language: "Swedish", i18n : "se_SE" }
    ];

    $scope.selectedType = $scope.languages[0].i18n;
}]);
```

**Notes:**

- Have removed the `$translate` service for ease of reproduction.
- Have changed an `ng-changed` callback to a `$watch` on the `$scope` but that is merely aesthetic choice.
- The crucial change was that you were choosing the `lang.i18n` for `type` but were setting `type` to `lang.language`, thus resulting in no matches in the `option`s list.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I will leave it as an answer.

The Ramesh Rajendran answer is right, but you tried using a different `ngOptions` syntax.
If you use the `label for value in array` syntax, then you have to bind the model attribute to the entire object.
If you use the syntax in your comment, which is `select as label for value in array` then you have to bind the model to the select.

In order words, his example works, and to your example on the comment to work you need to replace `$scope.selectedlanguage = $scope.languages[0];` with `$scope.selectedlanguage = $scope.languages[0].i18n;`

Check the [select directive documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) for further information

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$scope.prop = { "values": 
[ {name:'hello1',id:1},{name:'hello2',id:2},{name:'hello3',id:3}] };
$scope.selectedValue = 2; 

<select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="v.id as v.name for v in prop.values">
    <option selected value="">Select option</option>
</select>
```

live example: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JqNqNRku9eM8QLpLQpcc?p=preview)