# Default value for <select> using ng-input

Tags: angular, select, default, ng-init, ngmodel

Is there any way to set default value for select in my case without using controller?

I've tried many ways. This is the last one...

```
<select [(ngModel)]="model.carColour" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" class="form-control input-sm" ng-init="model.carColour='select'">
     <option value="select">Select color</option> 
     <option></option>   
     <option *ngFor="let item of carscolours" [value]="item.value"> {{item.text}}</option>  
 </select>
```

I need set "Select color" as default, and in the dropdown list will be empty string and items from library.

Comment: Question still actual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the answer. Maybe someone will need it...

```
<select [(ngModel)]="model.carColour"  #States="ngModel" name="carColours" class="form-control input-sm" >
       <option [ngValue]="model.carColour" hidden>Please, select...</option>
       <option></option>
       <option *ngFor="let item of carscolours" [ngValue]="item.value" >{{item.text}}</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thanks! - I've been looking for exactly this!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<option selected="selected">Select Color</option>
```

Comment: I don't understand how that wouldn't work. When you inspect that option, does it not have those attributes on it? And what is it defaulting to?

Comment: it work if there is no ngModel in the <select>. What I need? That in the view "Select color" was displayed like placeholder  in the combobox.

Comment: Luckily your question has been asked countless times before. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329495/how-to-use-ng-option-to-set-default-value-of-select-element or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194255/how-to-have-a-default-option-in-angular-js-select-box or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007196/set-default-value-inside-ngselect . Try searching next time!

Comment: I searched for an hours. And saw all this answers. They didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I suspect you're not implementing the solution properly then, but you haven't shown any JS code of what you've actually tried, so we can't tell you what you did wrong. I'm not familiar with Angular unfortunately, but it looks to be something you set in the configuration, but lot of answers showing many ways of tackling it.